# What is this quantity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, ramanujan-summation

I wonder whether there is a closed form for

$$-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Delta^{k}\pi(x)}{k!}(-x)_k$$

where $\pi(x)$ is the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) and $(x)_k$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

In other words I want a Ramanujan's summation of the prime numbers membership function.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to believe such a closed form exists?